# Problems with creating daily mean with many missing values

Tags: r, date, dplyr, mean, lubridate

I created this dataframe, which is very representive for my data, sorry for the long code.

```
library(lubridate)

datelist = seq(ymd_hms('1980-01-01 00:00:00'),ymd_hms('1980-07-01 00:00:00'), by = '60 mins')

df = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,4000,rep=TRUE)))
nbr_missing<-1000
y<-data.frame(row=sample(nrow(df),size = nbr_missing,replace = T),
              col=sample(ncol(df),size = nbr_missing,replace = T))

y<-y[!duplicated(y),]
df[as.matrix(y)]<-NA

df2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,369,rep=TRUE)))
nbr_missing<-500
xy<-data.frame(row=sample(nrow(df2),size = nbr_missing,replace = T),
               col=sample(ncol(df2),size = nbr_missing,replace = T))

xy<-xy[!duplicated(xy),]
df2[as.matrix(xy)]<-NA

fill1 = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 4000, ncol = 2))
fill2 = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 369, ncol = 2))

df_new1 = rbind(df, fill2)
df_new2 = rbind(fill1, df2)
df_new = cbind(df_new1, df_new2)

testframe = as.data.frame(cbind(datelist,df_new))
colnames(testframe) = c("Date", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
```

I am having problems with calculating a daily mean. I used this code several times with other data and it always worked great. But here it seems to give me the wrong results. Any idea why and how to solve this?

```
library(dplyr)
testframe1 = testframe %>%
  group_by(group = gl(n()/24, 24)) %>%
  summarise_at(-1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

For example the column JKL, it contains only NA in my hourly data for the first day, but when I create a mean, it gives me a number and not NA!

Here is an example of what I get when using this command.

[Hourly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vtyL.png)

[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2JXH.png)

Comment: Seems like you have only `NA`s in certain groups and thus the mean is `NaN`.

Comment: Thats not my problem. For example the column JKL, it contains only NA in my hourly data for the first day, but when I create a mean, it says 84 and not NA!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Can you start a new R session, run the code from start to end and post---if the error still occurs---the observed (and desired) output?

Comment: Can you please look again in my post? I added some pictures of my problem. This occures when I restart and also when I use another computer.

Comment: I strongly believe that `mean()` and `summarise()` work as expected here. The error is either in the data or in the grouping. Are the groups of the correct size (try `tally()`)? Or try something like `testframe %>% group_by(as.Date(Date)) %>% tally()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong with the `dplyr` code, you could use a `by()` approach with `colMeans()` instead.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(testframe[-1], as.Date(testframe1$Date), colMeans, na.rm=TRUE))
head(res)
#                 ABC      DEF GHI JKL
# 1980-01-01 74.25000 67.91304 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-02 52.70833 55.33333 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-03 65.37500 79.10000 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-04 48.61905 62.91667 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-05 62.34783 61.40909 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-06 80.38095 64.68182 NaN NaN
```

The `"group"` you could just `cbind()`.

```
res2 <- cbind(group=1:nrow(res), res)
head(res2)
#            group      ABC      DEF GHI JKL
# 1980-01-01     1 74.25000 67.91304 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-02     2 52.70833 55.33333 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-03     3 65.37500 79.10000 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-04     4 48.61905 62.91667 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-05     5 62.34783 61.40909 NaN NaN
# 1980-01-06     6 80.38095 64.68182 NaN NaN
```